# How to make gcp cloud function public using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform, google-iam

I will start by saying I am very new to both GCP and Terraform, so I hope there is a simple answer that I have just overlooked.

I am trying to create a GCP cloud function and then make it public using Terraform. I am able to create the function but not make it public, despite closely following the documentation's example: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_function.html

I receive the error "googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on resource ... (or resource may not exist)" when the google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member resource is reached.

How can I make this function public? Does it have something to do with the account/api key I am using for credentials to create all these resources?

Thanks in advance.

**my main.tf file:**

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "my-project"
  credentials = "key.json" #compute engine default service account api key
  region      = "us-central1"
}

terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "manually-created-bucket"
    prefix  = "terraform/state"
    credentials = "key.json"
  }
}

# create the storage bucket for our scripts
resource "google_storage_bucket" "source_code" {
  name     = "test-bucket-lh05111992"
  location = "us-central1"
  force_destroy = true
}

# zip up function source code
data "archive_file" "my_function_script_zip" {
 type        = "zip"
 source_dir  = "../source/scripts/my-function-script"
 output_path = "../source/scripts/my-function-script.zip"
}

# add function source code to storage
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "my_function_script_zip" {
 name   = "index.zip"
 bucket = google_storage_bucket.source_code.name
 source = "../source/scripts/my-function-script.zip"
}

#create the cloudfunction 
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name        = "send_my_function_script"
  description = "This function is called in GTM. It sends a users' google analytics id to BigQuery."
  runtime     = "nodejs10"

  available_memory_mb   = 128
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.source_code.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.my_function_script_zip.name
  trigger_http          = true
  entry_point           = "handleRequest"
}

# IAM entry for all users to invoke the function 
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "invoker" {
  project        = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.project
  region         = "us-central1"
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.name
  
  role = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member = "allUsers"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems the only problem with that example from the terraform site are the " Cloud Functions IAM resources" which have been modified since Nov 2019. Now you have to specify these resources as explained [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_cloud_function_iam.html#google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_binding). Now for your user case (public cloud function) I'd recommend you to follow [this configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_cloud_function_iam.html#google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_binding) and just change the "members" attribute to "allUsers" so it'd be something like this

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_binding" "binding" {
  project = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.project
  region = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.region
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.name
  role = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  members = [
    "allUsers",
  ]
}
```

Finally, you can give it a test and modify the functions you've already created [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/setIamPolicy) at the #Try this API" right panel and enter the proper resource and request body like this (make sure to enter the "resource" parameter correcly):

```
{
  "policy": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "members": [
          "allUsers"
        ],
        "role": "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the update in the IAM resources.

Comment: Using cloudfunctions2? [You need to modify the iam for cloudrun](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/5833#issuecomment-1237493434) rather than the cloud function itself

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adjusting the IAM roles how @chinoche suggested, I also discovered that I needed to modify the service account I was using to give it poject owner permissions. (I guess the default one I was using didn't have this). I updated my key.json and it finally worked.

Comment: You don't have to give the owner permissions to your SA, your just need to add this permission; cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy 
The best way to achieve this is by applying the least privilege principle by creating your own custom role and then attaching it to your SA.